# Setup ntp client with embedded device

Tags: embedded, arm, ntp

I need to run an NTP client on a very limited embedded device.

`ntpd` is available but I do not see anything like `rc.conf`, or `ntp.conf`, or `xntp.conf`?  Can someone advise on how to setup NTP?

I ran `ntpd`, but the date and time haven't updated.

Comment: Try [ntpdate](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V51B_HTML/MAN/MAN8/0329____.HTM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have the Busybox version of `ntpd`.  Here's a useful HOWTO:

http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/ntp.client

For example:

```
ntpd -q -p ptbtime1.ptb.de
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ntpd -bq`

That will set the time and quit. It will allow you to sync to broadcast servers as well.

That said there are two important things to note. First I don't know who the NTP servers are on you network. If someone is being a bad little techie they could bork your time/date and invalidate some security protocols.

Also be aware that a common problem is that your time is "ahead" of the NTP servers. so when you adjust your time, your files and other things exist in the future. This can really confuse things.  Linux doesn't like time travel and it's not afraid to let you know. Normally this is just warnings but can be more serious issues depending on how some scripts are written. I say this because an embedded device usually has some pretty narly scripts on it.

Comment: What do you mean by it? Isn't ntpd supposed to synchronize with the servers?

Comment: ntpd can sync to a "broadcast" server. A ntp server that broadcasts on your network. This is less secure as anyone can setup a broadcast server. It's common for some routers to broadcast NTP as do some OSes. The command I gave syncs one time then exits. But that assumes a standard version of ntpd

Comment: What common routers and/or OSs provide broadcast ntp service? Maybe you meant "it is not common to find ntp broadcast service"?

Comment: cisco routers, and windows active directory servers to name  couple right off the top of my head.